# Question about using grep

Tags: regex, search, grep

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/ HTTP/1.1" 200 169 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/.treeinfo HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Fedora HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Server HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Client HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/RedHat HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/CentOS HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/SL HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/directory.yast HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/current/images/MANIFEST HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/images/daily/MANIFEST HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/boot/platform/i86xpv/kernel/unix HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/platform/i86xpv/kernel/unix HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/STARTUP/XNLOADER.SYS HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/images/xen/vmlinuz HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/images/boot.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/boot/boot.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/current/images/netboot/mini.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:27 +0530] "HEAD /sk/install/images/boot.iso HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/ HTTP/1.1" 200 169 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/.treeinfo HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Fedora HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Server HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/Client HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/RedHat HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/CentOS HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/SL HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/directory.yast HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2011:00:26:35 +0530] "HEAD /sk/current/images/MANIFEST HTTP/1.1" 404 182 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6"
```

I am having a file of above structure and it is name log.txt.
Now I do

```
 cat log.txt | grep '[*]'
```

there was no output 
then I did

```
 cat log.txt | grep '\[* \]'
```

again there was no output
but when I did

```
 cat log.txt | grep '\[.*\]'
```

then there was output how is this working?

**UPTADE**

I am basically trying to look for the time stamps in above log.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash`, `string-manipulation` or `sed`. What output were you expecting for each? Which lines are you trying to extract from `log.txt`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It's not possible to deduce this from your attempted commands.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I expected the lines which contain time stamp in [ ] to come in the grep result.Try the last command on your system.

Comment: @Registered User so *every* line in your Apache access log? You'd be better using `cat` by itself. If you're looking for the timestamp in square brackets then you'll need a [Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) like `grep '\[[0-9]\{2\}/[A-Za-z]\{3\}/[0-9]\{4\}\(:[0-9]\{2\}\)\{3\} +[0-9]\{4\}\]' log.txt`

Comment: @Johnsyweb now you got me I am trying to look for the time stamps.

Comment: @Registered User: Then my regular expression, along with the `grep` [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/grep/) should help you. If you can't manage I suggest you start a new question explaining what you are trying to do (with expected output) and how you have tried to do it. @codeaddict has answered this question sufficiently, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cat log.txt | grep '[*]'
```

This command line searches the file `log.txt` for lines that contain a `*` in them. Since none of the lines in your input have `*` you get nothing. Note that `[..]` in regex is called a character class which matches any of the character inside it.

```
cat log.txt | grep '\[* \]'
```

This command line searches the file for lines that have zero or more of literal `[` followed by a space and followed by a literal `]`. Again you don't have any such lines. Here you've escaped the `[` and `]`. This makes them non-special. So they don't form a character class anymore but are treated literally.

```
cat log.txt | grep '\[.*\]'
```

This one searches for lines that have a `[` followed by anything (`.*`) followed by a `]`. Since you have such lines you get the output.

Finally

```
 cat file | grep pattern
```

is called useless use of cat and can be written as:

```
grep pattern file
```

Comment: I got your point now.I was actually not able to explain my question properly I basically wanted to grep the time stamps and for that I was using such things.

Answer (score 1):

In regexes the point "." means "any character" and the star "*" means: match me if the character before me is present 0 or more times.
"[" and "]" are used to limit a class of characters.

So:

1. "[*]" matches only a star
2. "\[*\[" means take any '[' followed by a ']'
3. "\[.*\]" take anything which starts with a '[' followed by any char, followed by a '\]'

Answer (score 1):

grep uses a regular expression as a pattern. The one you wrote (last one) means

- [ : the '[' character once
- .* : any character (.) any times from 0 to infinity (*)
- ] : the ']' character once

Writing `\[*\]` would mean "The '[' character any number of times and then the ']' character".
As writing `[*]` wouldn't mean anything since `[]` is the marker for a group of characters.
There is a short explanation of regular expressions in `man grep` and you may find much more [online](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)